# Power supply unit with two negative and positive outputs

Tags: power-supply, output, ac-dc

So I am trying to add a power supply unit, which takes one input and supposed to provide one output:

IN: 85-265V AC

OUT:12V DC; 25A (max output power 300W)

However, when I look at it, it clearly has two negative and positive output terminals. I am not sure why is that and what I supposed to do with the second positive & negative output terminals, maybe someone could explain me?

The photo: the manual says +V  +V  -V  -V  stand for 2 positive and negative output terminals, L & N for live and neutral input terminals:

[image]

You can find the manual [here](https://uk.tdk-lambda.com/KB/RWS50B600B-Installation-Manual.pdf)

Thank you!

Comment: Both +V will be +12Vdc and both -V will be ground. The second pair of terminals is for connection convenience and you don't need to use them if you only have one load.

Comment: The manufacturer has provided two terminals simply to make it easier to make multiple connections. The two + terminals are shorted together and the two - terminals are shorted together (they are not separate  12 V supplies).  The 12 V supply is NOT grounded, it is floating, you can ground either the + or - side of the supply depending on what you need.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, 25 amps would require fairly thick wires, this allows you to easily use pairs of thinner wire.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! So regarding the grounding, do I need to ground my +12V and/or -12V output, and if yes, do I just connect it together with the wire, coming out of the grounded terminal? I've read quite a bit about grounding, but still not sure, if it is necessary in each case.